# Force acronyms to be upper case sphinx?

Tags: sphinx, case-sensitive

Searches for 'HR' as in Human Resources is returning docs with hr e.g $90 hr. I've tried wordforms to no avail and am stuck. I understand it may be possible to change char_set but that will mean I lose the ability to match any other cases. This must be an issue for Sphinx search in general does anyone have a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to solve this would be with `regexp_filter`, which can do case sensitive replacements.

Something like...

```
regexp_filter = \b([A-Z]{2,})\b => upper_\1
```

It will replace it with different word, but the upper prefix, will survive charset_table lower-casing the tokens.

Comment: So this above basically says any two-letter for turn into upper case? Then I'm left with 3 and 4 letter acronyms which could clearly introduce issues as doing {2,4} would surely break a lot more than it would fix. I'm probably going to have to extend my internal logic and push some ! into specific acronyms.

Comment: any 2 or more letter uppercase word, will only match uppercase. It doesnt actully turn it uppercase, turns 'HR' into 'upper_hr'. Searching for say `upper_hr` would match `HR`, just not `hr`

Comment: Interesting idea, meaning I force searches on acronyms to be upper_$acornym. I added your regexp to the wordforms and then searched however on a variety of sample records with 'HR' and 'hr'. searching for upper_hr returns nothing. Is there any other index setting that needs to be on to make this work? It is a good work around solution since i can control how input acronyms are pushed.

Comment: `added your regexp to the wordforms` huh? That makes no sense. Regex filters are nothing to do with wordforms. They go directly in the source config.

Comment: Newbie error sorry, worked. With a caveat; when I put that in the config, NEAR/ fails " unexpected '/' near '/10 ". If I comment the regexp_filter out the same comment works.